# Getting error while converting on FFMPEG? what's the meaning & how it should be fixed?

Tags: ffmpeg, converters, watermark

I am using this code to apply watermark on linux server;

```
-i input.mp4 logo.png -filter_complex 'overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10' output.mp4
```

so ended-up with this error;

```
Please use -b:a or -b:v, -b is ambiguous
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_overlay_0
```

Full error;

```
ffmpeg version N-71954-gbc6f84f Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --enable-shared --

enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --

enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopencore-

amrnb --enable-postproc --enable-nonfree --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --

enable-libfaac --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-zlib --disable-doc

  libavutil      54. 23.101 / 54. 23.101
  libavcodec     56. 37.101 / 56. 37.101
  libavformat    56. 31.102 / 56. 31.102
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'uploaded/1502539665_21.mp4':

  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.31.102
    enter code here

  Duration: 00:02:27.32, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 635 kb/s

    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x320 
[SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2], 476 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)

    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    enter code here
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 151 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    enter code here

Please use -b:a or -b:v, -b is ambiguous
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_overlay_0
```

Answer (score 3):

Your image isn't presented as an input so ffmpeg treats it as the first output, and output.mp4 as the 2nd output. The filter_complex only sees the video as an input.

Start your command like this

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i logo.png
```